# Is Isaiah Berlin's distinction between positive and negative freedom trivially exhaustive?

Tags: freedom

Are Isaiah [Berlin's](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/berlin/) positive and negative freedoms trivially exhaustive? Wikiepdia says he argued for:

> the need for us to distinguish and trade off analytically between,
>   rather than conflate, them, if we are to avoid disguising underlying
>   value-conflicts. The [two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_Berlin#.22Two_Concepts_of_Liberty.22) concepts are 'negative freedom', or freedom
>   from interference, which Berlin derived from the British tradition,
>   and 'positive freedom', or freedom as self-mastery, which asks not
>   what we are free from, but what we are free to do.

Comment: Can you add a brief explanation of the difference to your post? That would make the thread easier to follow.

Comment: It is easily argued that any genuine freedom is, in effect, a negative freedom.  If I am to do something, at some point you must be restrained from preventing me from doing it, or I do not have the freedom.  That makes positive freedoms a subset of negative freedoms.  So then just that one category is trivially exhaustive.